# MYSQL , Count week wise and also show sum with empty dates

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have two tables

Table_1 : Routes_Day_plan

```
Date        Status_Id
------------------------
2019-06-09  1
2019-06-10  2
2019-06-09  2
2019-06-11  3
2019-06-14  4
2019-06-14  6
2019-06-15  8
```

Table_2 : Codes

```
id code
-------
1  Leave
2  Half_leave
3  Holiday
4  Work
5  Full_Hours
```

Now my task is to count week wise from table 1 where code (from second table) = Leave,Half_leave,work and than also show the sum , and where date not found show  0 , i write this query it's return data but not empty dates can someone please help ,

My Query:

```
select COUNT(*) as available, DATE(date) 
from Table_1 
where status_id in (
   select id from codes 
   where code in ('Leave','Half_leave','work')) 
AND DATE(date) >= DATE('2019-06-09') AND DATE(date) <= DATE('2019-06-16') 
group by date 

UNION ALL 

SELECT COUNT(date), 'SUM' date 
FROM Table_1 
where status_id in (
   select id from codes 
   where code in ('Leave','Half_leave','work')) 
AND DATE(date) >= DATE('2019-06-09') AND DATE(date) <= DATE('2019-06-16')
```

Result Something Like ,

```
available   Dates
------------------------
5      2019-06-09
2      2019-06-10
3      2019-06-11
3      2019-06-12
2      2019-06-14
2      2019-06-15
17     SUM
```

I want like this

```
available  Dates
------------------------
5      2019-06-09
2      2019-06-10
3      2019-06-11
3      2019-06-12
0      2019-06-13
2      2019-06-14
2      2019-06-15
17     SUM
```

Comment: Do you have a dates/calendar table?

Comment: No dates came from back-end , admin can send dates week wise , from any year or month

Comment: How does `2019-06-09` date count as `5`? or `2019-06-10` count as `2`?

Comment: What does this have to do with week if you're expecting a count, date table??

Comment: it just an example result .

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here would be to have a Date Dimension/Lookup table which contains pre-populated dates for the entire year. By joining your record table to this lookup, you essentially allocate your data to each date that actually exist (ex. 2019-06-13) and if your data is not found in the lookup, you will find a null in that field.

The Count function will count a null as a 0. Just make sure you group on the date field from your lookup table and not from your record table.

Answer (score 0):

Make a table, a date dimension that contains all the dates value, from beginning to end. Like this:

```
Set EndDate = '2099-01-01'; 
Set RunDate = '1900-01-01';
WHILE RunDate <= EndDate DO
insert into dim_date
(`DATE`)
select
RunDate as DATE
;



Set RunDate = ADDDATE(RunDate,1);

END WHILE;
```

Create temporary table with dim_date left join Routes_Day_plan and set Status as 0 maybe for record that dont match. Use this temporary table then instead of Routes_Day_plan in your queries.